# How do link the first level like localhost/About and localhost/Faq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I make Views/About/Index.aspx and Views/Faq/Index.aspx + Controllers/AboutController.cs and Controllers/FaqController.cs controllers for these purposes.

I want to have one controller Controllers/DefaultController.cs + Views/About.aspx and Views/Faq.aspx in the root, for example.

How to set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 private static readonly string[] StaticPages = 
                                   {
                                       "FaQ", "Help"
                                   };

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the routes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="routes">The routes.</param>
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("StaticPages",
            "{id}", // url
            new { controller = "StaticPages", action = "Show" }, // defaults
            new { id = String.Join("|", StaticPages) }); // constraints


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }); // Parameter defaults
    }
```

Comment: For all controllers you will have "Default" route to work. For static pages like FAQ, Help you will create StaticPages controller, with appropriate actions.

Comment: Well done! Clarification. Views placed in the Views\Shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what, your `*.aspx` files for the Views should stay in the `Views/{Name}/{PageName}.aspx` style.

If you want a URL like `http://localhost/About`, you set up a default route in `Global.asax.cs` to point to the proper Action.